# Method is not working properly onClick submit

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Empty form object is saving in array on submit.
when i submit the button. I want to add form object in array and then reset values of form object.
The problem is when I click the submit button first it reset then push object into array.

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <form @submit.prevent="addIntoArr">
      <input type="text" v-model="form.input1" />
      <p>{{ form.input1 }}</p>
      <button type="submit">add me</button>
    </form>
    <!-- <Apply /> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// import Footer from "../components/footerFr/header.vue";

// import Apply from "../components/apply.vue";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components: {
    // Apply,
  },
  data: () => {
    return {
      arr: [],
      form: {
        input1: "",
        input2: "",
        input3: "",
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addIntoArr() {
      console.log("form", this.form);
      this.arr.push(this.form);
      console.log("arr", this.arr);
      this.form.input1 = "";
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.home {
  width: 100%;
}
input {
  border: black 1px solid;
}
button[type="submit"] {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Suppose i type input1="ddjsnkjfns" and then when I click submit button.
it suppose to print form object like this

```
form={
   input1:"ddjsnkjfns",
   input2:"",
   input2:""
}
```

Then push this object into arr array.

But it prints empty object like this

```
form={
   input1:"",
   input2:"",
   input2:""
}
```

and then save empty object into arr array.

**before submit**
[image]

**after submit**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for what you see is most browser today when you log an object show the live version ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log#logging_objects)) - so what you see is not the value at the time `log` statement was executed

To workaround this, you should log stringified value: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)))`

Second problem is you seem not understand how objects work in JS. Following code:

```js
this.arr.push(this.form);
this.form.input1 = "";
```

1. pushes the reference to `form` object into the array
2. modifies **the same object** (only through different reference)

[Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

So the correct way is actually to make a copy of the object when pushing (by using destructuring in my example):

```js
this.arr.push({...this.form});
this.form.input1 = "";
```